# Pagination with Laravel and with()

Tags: php, laravel

I have an eloquent request to pick up my category and related questions.

I would like the `questions` section to have a pagination.

```
  public function index()
  {
    $data = Category::where([
      ['slug', '=', 'interview-questions'],
      ['lang', '=', auth()->user()->lang],
      ['profile_id', '=', auth()->user()->profile_id]
    ])->with(
      [
        'questions' => function ($query) {
          $query->whereNull('parent_id')->with(
            [
              'answer' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
              },
            ]
          )->orderBy('position', 'ASC')->paginate(15);
        }
      ]
    )->first();
}
```

Here's what I get:

```
data: {id: 31, title: "Interview - Questions", slug: "interview-questions", part: "interview-questions",…}
created_at: "2019-08-22 16:28:33"
deleted_at: null
id: 31
lang: "fr"
part: "interview-questions"
profile_id: 1
   questions: [{id: 956, question: "<h3>1. Qu’est-ce qui vous a intéressé dans notre annonce ?&nbsp;</h3>",…},…]
      0: {id: 956, question: "<h3>1. Qu’est-ce qui vous a intéressé dans notre annonce ?&nbsp;</h3>",…}
      1: {id: 957,…}
      2: {id: 958,…}
      3: {id: 959, question: "<h3>4. Depuis combien de temps cherchez-vous du travail&nbsp;?</h3>",…}
      4: {id: 960,…}
      5: {id: 961,…}
      6: {id: 962,…}
      7: {id: 963,…}
      8: {id: 964, question: "<h3>9. Pourquoi avez-vous postulé chez nous&nbsp;(candidature spontanée) ?</h3>",…}
     9: {id: 965,…}
     10: {id: 966, question: "<h3>11. Racontez-moi vos expériences professionnelles.</h3>", type: "wysiwyg",…}
```

My questions are well limited to 10.. Only, I don't have pagination information like Laravel should provide them like `first_page_url`, `per_page`, `total`, `next_page_url`, and so on…

Why ? And how to solve this problem?

Comment: You don't need to use first() or get() while using pagination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to paginate your relation, if you have good models I think you can do something like this:

```
public function index()
  {
    $data = Category::where([
      ['slug', '=', 'interview-questions'],
      ['lang', '=', auth()->user()->lang],
      ['profile_id', '=', auth()->user()->profile_id]
    ])->with(
      [
        'questions' => function ($query) {
          $query->whereNull('parent_id')->with(
            [
              'answer' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
              },
            ]
          )->orderBy('position', 'ASC');
        }
      ]
    )->first();

    $data = $data->questions()->paginate(15);
}
```

Or you can separately paginate your relation data and send it as new variable:

```
$questions = $data->questions()->paginate(15);
```

If you have any errors provide it here.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using pagination in wrong place, and you are also using `first()` - which only gets first data that it finds from filter. Change your code to this:

```
 public function index(){
    $data = Category::where([
      ['slug', '=', 'interview-questions'],
      ['lang', '=', auth()->user()->lang],
      ['profile_id', '=', auth()->user()->profile_id]
    ])->with(
      [
        'questions' => function ($query) {
          $query->whereNull('parent_id')->with(
            [
              'answer' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
              },
            ]
          )->orderBy('position', 'ASC');
        }
      ]
    )->paginate(15);
}
```

Not tested, but should give you desired result. Let me know if you have any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `first()` or `get()` method with pagination as pagination itself fetch the number of results you have given as an argument (limit).
ie for your case, it will fetch first 15 results and paginate accordingly. on accessing other pages, it simply adds offset with the limit.

Below is a sample code.
NOTE: The pagination will be applied to Categories, not on the questions.

```php
public function index(){
    $data = Category::where([
        ['slug', '=', 'interview-questions'],
        ['lang', '=', auth()->user()->lang],
        ['profile_id', '=', auth()->user()->profile_id]
    ])->with([
        'questions' => function ($query) {
            $query->whereNull('parent_id')->with([
                'answer' => function ($query) {
                    $query->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
                },
            ])->orderBy('position', 'ASC');
        }
    ])->paginate(15);
}
```

Comment: I think he know that, but he need to paginate the questions for one Category... @Satendra Rawat

Comment: Thanks for your consideration @mare96. You have given the answer then. Glad!!